# PostgreSQL. Slow queries in log file are fast in psql

Tags: postgresql, logging, query-optimization

I have an application written on Play Framework 1.2.4 with Hibernate(default C3P0 connection pooling) and PostgreSQL database (9.1).

Recently I turned on slow queries logging ( >= 100 ms) in postgresql.conf and found some issues.

But when I tried to analyze and optimize one particular query, I found that it is blazing fast in psql (0.5 - 1 ms) in comparison to 200-250 ms in the log. The same thing happened with the other queries.

The application and database server is running on the same machine and communicating using localhost interface.

JDBC driver - postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4

I wonder what could be wrong, because query duration in the log is calculated considering only database processing time excluding external things like network turnarounds etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibility 1: If the slow queries occur occasionally or in bursts, it could be checkpoint activity. Enable checkpoint logging (`log_checkpoints = on`), make sure the log level (`log_min_messages`) is 'info' or lower, and see what turns up. Checkpoints that're taking a long time or happening too often suggest you probably need some checkpoint/WAL and bgwriter tuning. This isn't likely to be the cause if the same statements are always slow and others always perform well.

Possibility 2: Your query plans are different because you're running them directly in `psql` while Hibernate, via PgJDBC, will at least sometimes be doing a `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` (at the protocol level so you won't see actual statements). For this, compare query performance with `PREPARE test_query(...) AS SELECT ...` then `EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE test_query(...)`. The parameters in the PREPARE are type names for the positional parameters ($1,$2,etc); the parameters in the EXECUTE are values.

If the prepared plan is different to the one-off plan, you can set [PgJDBC's prepare threshold](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/server-prepare.html) via connection parameters to tell it never to use server-side prepared statements.

This difference between the plans of prepared and unprepared statements [should go away in PostgreSQL 9.2](http://lwn.net/Articles/497264/). It's been a long-standing wart, but Tom Lane dealt with it for the up-coming release.

Comment: any insight into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786949/duration-logged-but-not-the-statement-postgresql-are-there-any-specific-quer

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons. First if the database was very busy when the slow queries excuted, the query may be slower. So you may need to observe the load of the OS at that moment for future analysis.

Second the history plan of the sql may be different from the current session plan. So you may need to install [auto_explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auto-explain.html) to see the actual plan of the slow query.

Comment: Totally agree, sample `load average` along with slow query logging to get a full picture.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to say for sure without knowing all the details of your system, but I can think of a couple of possibilities:

- **The query results are cached.** If you run the same query twice in a short space of time, it will almost always complete much more quickly on the second pass. PostgreSQL maintains a cache of recently retrieved data for just this purpose. If you are pulling the queries from the tail of your log and executing them immediately this could be what's happening.
- **Other processes are interfering.** The execution time for a query varies depending on what else is going on in the system. If the queries are taking 100ms during peak hour on your website when a lot of users are connected but only 1ms when you try them again late at night this could be what's happening.

The point is you are correct that the query duration isn't affected by which library or application is calling it, so the difference must be coming from something else. Keep looking, good luck!

Comment: Well. Considering htop and top output the database server is not overloaded at all. I have 2 proc box. and load average is near 0.9 - 1 which is low. Anyway, thaks for the tips.

Comment: Yeah, these are just the obvious answers but I see you know what you're doing. franc's auto_explain suggestion sounds like a good next step.