# Duration logged but not the statement -- postgresql. Are there any specific queries for this behavior?

Tags: postgresql, logging

I have the following setting in my `postgresql.conf`

```
log_statement='all'
log_duration=on
```

When I run psql, and run any query like select/create user/ etc, it logs the statement as well as the duration. If I give the query to connect to a different database

```
\c <database_name>
```

it logs neither the duration nor the statement. I thought it might not log duration and statement for meta-commands that starts with a backslash. But it does log the statement and duration for some of them, like `\dt` `\l`.

I think there might be a list of queries/commands, for which log will be generated or not. is there any such list?

Having said that, the original issue, that led me to dig this is --

My application (golang-react application) interacts with postgresql and logs statement and its duration. But after that it logs two more durations, whose statement is not printed. (I have commented `log_min_duration_statement`), so I'm not sure what queries, this duration is for. 
Also if I do `SELECT query,xact_start,query_start FROM pg_stat_activity;` at that time to see the running queries,it does not show any other query than the one which I see in the logs.

How can I know which queries is this duration for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But after that it logs two more durations, whose statement is not printed.

These are probably the parse, bind and execute durations for the three phases of statement execution, if you have `log_duration = on`. It's only done in three phases via client applications - `psql` runs in a single go.

If you just want the total, use `log_min_duration_statement = 0` instead.

Yes, that's confusing. Maybe it's worth writing it up and submitting it as a usability problem report to pgsql-general.

Comment: Thanks for taking out sometime for answering. You are right, its parse, bind and execute durations. Now that I give log_min_duration_statement=0 it does tell me the phase along with the duration of time it spent on that phase. But I didn't understand the total bit. It does not print the total instead, even if I make log_min_duration_statement to be zero. Is there a way we can do that? btw I'm happy with the logging of phases.